# How to know when the data from observable is ready to use in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I was trying to write a small web app using Angular 4 and NodeJS when I found it difficult to write a function that use a variable which will be initialized and update by my service.
Here is my snippets:

```
getStudentsBySessionId() {
  this.sessionService
    .getStudentsBySession(this._sessionId)
    .subscribe(students => {
      this.sessionStudents = students;
      this.reInitDatatable();
  });
}

isAdded(studentId){
  this.sessionStudents.forEach(student => {
    if(student._id === studentId){
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

However, when isAdded function is called in the template file, the error undefined of sessionStudents is raised.

How can I properly write the program in this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about initializing sessionStudents to an empty array? Then I believe the function call in the template file would work. Assuming the following is your component...

```
class YourComponent {

  sessionStudents = [];

  getStudentsBySessionId() {
    this.sessionService
      .getStudentsBySession(this._sessionId)
      .subscribe(students => {
        this.sessionStudents = students;
        ...
      });
  }

  isAdded(studentId){
    ...
  }

}
```

I believe the template should automatically pick up on the change when the value of sessionStudents is reassigned in the subscription's success handler.

Does this help?

Comment: The return value is used in the ngIf in the template but the condition never changes. (It returns false when init and return true when the data is available but the condition in the template never changes so ngIf always in the false case). Can you show me how to make it work?

Comment: No, I can't make it work. The value in the template never changes. I don't know why.